# Basic Apache2 vhost configuration doesn't work

Tags: apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I have a litle problem with my virtual host configuration on Apache2.

Context : I have a Raspberry Pi with Apache2 installed. I want to access to my test directory in : "/var/www/html/test".

So I modified my 000-default.conf in "/etc/apache2/sites-available" like this and this worked:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>

            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    </VirtualHost>


    NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.29:80

    <VirtualHost 192.168.1.29:80>
    ServerName raspyvan
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test
    </VirtualHost>



    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

*(raspyvan is my servername on my router ans host file)*

But I would deny the access with IP adress "192.168.1.29"

So I modified in a second time my 000-default.conf file like this :

```
Listen 192.168.1.29:80

ServerName DefaultServer
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.29:80


<VirtualHost 192.168.1.29:80>
        ServerName 192.168.1.29

        <Directory />
                Deny from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost 192.168.1.29:80>
                ServerName raspyvan
                DocumentRoot /var/www/test
</VirtualHost>



# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Now the problem is that the access by IP and hostname are denied and I don't know why.

Edit : My nameserver is apply on the DNS router config and hosts apache file.

Answer (score 0):

when apache can't match a vhost it will always use the first vhost it comes across (this is why we historically needed one ip per ssl cert until sni came along).

add a log per vhost;

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-default.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-default.log combined
```

and

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-raspyvan.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-raspyvan.log combined
```

check the log file "access-default.log" to see which hostname has been requested.

Comment: Thanks. I have add log per vhost but these files are not created when I request on browser. These files are in "/var/log/apache2/" ?

Comment: did you restart or reload apache? if so they'll be in /var/log/apache2

Comment: Yes I have restart the apache service but no file are create. Moreover in other log files there are no log about the deny access.

Comment: `CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-raspyvan.log combined` use full path and try

Comment: Thanks. But there are no log file created. I don't understand how apache work on vhost logs.

Comment: Can you add an edit with the latest config you have, will tweek and put in an update to answer.